# Globally applied IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute doesn't disable ValidateAntiForgeryToken

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have an endpoint with those attributes:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
```

When I applied `IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` globally

```
.AddMvc(opts =>
{
    opts.Filters.Add(typeof(CustomExceptionFilter));
    opts.Filters.Add(new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
    // or
    opts.Filters.Add(typeof(IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute));
})
```

It didn't disable that `[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]`, but when I did something like that:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
[IgnoreAntiforgeryToken]
[Route("[controller]/[action]")]
```

then it was disabled, why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For built-in `ValidateAntiForgeryToken`, you could not disable it by `IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute` in the `Startup.cs`.  You could refre [Default order of execution](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/filters?view=aspnetcore-2.2#default-order-of-execution).

For a workaround, you could implement your own `ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` like

```
public class CustomValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter : ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter
{
    public CustomValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter(IAntiforgery antiforgery, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
        :base(antiforgery, loggerFactory)
    {
    }
    protected override bool ShouldValidate(AuthorizationFilterContext context)
    {
        var filters = context.Filters;
        if (filters.Where(f => f.GetType() == typeof(IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute)) != null)
        {
            return false;
        }
        else
        {
            return base.ShouldValidate(context);
        }
    }
}
```

And register by `ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter` like

```
services.AddMvc(options => {
    options.Filters.Insert(0, new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());

    options.Filters.Add(typeof(WebApiExceptionFilter)); // by type
});
services.AddScoped<ValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter, CustomValidateAntiforgeryTokenAuthorizationFilter > ();
```

Comment: this works fine, but I wish that was possible without defining those custom filters :/

Answer (score 1):

Try inserting the filter at the top of the list so it takes precedence of existing filters, such as the `AutoValidateAntiforgeryTokenAttribute`:

```cs
opts.Filters.Insert(0, new IgnoreAntiforgeryTokenAttribute());
```

Comment: I'd also specify the `Order` property in the ctor - it helps to apply it before the actual Antiforgery attribute on your controller or action.